# Is there a way to lock a bone layer?

Tags: armature, bones, layers

I know bones can be arranged by layers in the armature properties. Is it possible to somehow "lock" a layer so that all bones in that layer cannot be selected?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this function does not exist. Generally all collections, objects and bones can be set to non-selectable with the outliner filter `Selectable` which looks like an arrowhead. [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html#restriction-columns)

[image]

The filter acts on both modes at once - pose and editmode. Unfortunately you have to navigate through the armature hierarchy to find all the bones of one a layer and set the selectability individually.

You may want to give the following script a chance. It adds a menu to the skeleton panel on top of the layer field that allows to lock and unlock all or just the bones of the active layer(s).

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator

# special menu
class DATA_MT_skeleton_specials(Menu):
    bl_idname = "DATA_MT_skeleton_specials"
    bl_label = "Armature Layer Specials"

    def draw(self, _context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text="Selectable Bones")

        op = layout.operator('data.skeleton_specials_op', text="Lock All", icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_ON')
        op.do = "lock_all"
        op.descript = "Make all Bones non-selectable"

        op = layout.operator('data.skeleton_specials_op', text="Lock Layer", icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_ON')
        op.do = "lock_layer"
        op.descript = "Make Bones in active layer(s) non-selectable"

        op = layout.operator('data.skeleton_specials_op', text="Unlock All", icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF')
        op.do = "unlock_all"
        op.descript = "Make all Bones selectable"

        op = layout.operator('data.skeleton_specials_op', text="Unlock Layer", icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF')
        op.do = "unlock_layer"
        op.descript = "Make Bones in active layer(s) selectable"

# special op
class DATA_OT_skeleton_specials(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'data.skeleton_specials_op'
    bl_label = ""    
    do : bpy.props.StringProperty(default="")
    descript : bpy.props.StringProperty()  

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.mode == 'EDIT_ARMATURE':
            bone_data = context.armature.edit_bones
        else:
            bone_data = context.armature.bones

        bones = []
        layers = []

        set = False 
        if self.do.startswith('lock'):
            set = True

        if self.do.endswith('all'):
            bones = bone_data

        else:
            for idx, layer in enumerate(context.armature.layers):
                if layer:
                    layers.append(idx)                           

            for bone in bone_data:
                for layer in layers:
                    if bone.layers[layer]:
                        bones.append(bone)

        for bone in bones:
            bone_data[bone.name].hide_select = set

        return {'FINISHED'}  

    @classmethod
    def description(cls, context, properties):
        return properties.descript

### REGISTRY

def register():

    skeleton_draw_old = bpy.types.DATA_PT_skeleton.draw # store original

    bpy.utils.register_class(DATA_MT_skeleton_specials)     
    bpy.utils.register_class(DATA_OT_skeleton_specials)     

    def skeleton_draw_new(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        arm = context.armature

        layout.row().prop(arm, "pose_position", expand=True)

        col = layout.column()
        row = col.row()
        row.label(text="Layers:") 
        row.menu('DATA_MT_skeleton_specials', text="", icon='DOWNARROW_HLT')
        col.prop(arm, "layers", text="")
        col.label(text="Protected Layers:")
        col.prop(arm, "layers_protected", text="")    

    bpy.types.DATA_PT_skeleton.draw = skeleton_draw_new   # replace draw
            
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DATA_MT_skeleton_specials) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DATA_OT_skeleton_specials) 
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_skeleton.draw = skeleton_draw_old   # restore draw            
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Open a new text block in Scripting workspace, copy the whole script into it and press Run. The script is stored with the blenderfile but needs to be run again.

[image]

(tested in 2.93, 3.32, 3.51)